# unable to trigger event delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i am unable to trigger simple event delegation on my code, The dom elments within selected DIV are dynamically created.

```
<div class="holder" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
  <a class="jp-previous page1"> previous</a>
  <a class="page">1</a>
  <span class="jp-hidden">...</span>
  <a class="page jp-current">2</a>
  <a class="jp-next page1 jp-disabled">next </a>
</div>
```

Following is my JS Code which i am executing within ready block.

```
jQuery("div[class=holder]").on('click',function() {
        alert('i am here');
    });
```

Comment: your syntax is wrong `jQuery(document).on('click', "div[class=holder]", function() {..});` - also use a class selector instead of attribute selector so `jQuery(document).on('click', ".holder", function() {..});`

Comment: @ArunPJohny:already tried that its not working too

Comment: then try using a class selector as I said the updated comment

Comment: @ArunPJohny:thx your updated answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this....

```
jQuery(document).on('click','div[class=holder]',function() {
        alert('i am here');
    });
```

Can also use

```
 jQuery(document).on('click','.holder',function() {
            alert('i am here');
        });
```

Comment: `jQuery("document")`.....really????

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
jQuery(document).on('click',".holder",function() {
```